# How to make textarea with auto suggest from complex JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am looking autocomplete library which can support autocomplete for nested (lookup ) fields

Like I have Array of Data

```
var Data=[
  "Name",
  {
    "Employee": [
      "name",
      "address",
      "phone"
    ]
  },
  "Size",
  "LastName"
  {
    "Vacation": [
      "name",
      "address",
      "phone"
    ]
  }
]
```

If I type '**N**' then it should suggest Name, LastName

If I type '**E**' it should suggest Employee and

if I type **Employee** **.** then it should suggest properties of Employee object like name, address, and phone

Is there such flexibility with Jquery autocomplete library or if anyone knows a different library which has such flexibility, please suggest me.

Comment: yes, try to do auto complete with ajax. and on server side when you return json apply your conditions based on your requirements

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham I have all my data locally. Can you show some example for my case?

Comment: @Sam this can be done. Would need a bit more details to help with an example. For example, how should data be displayed? What happens when an item is selected?

Answer (score 0):

This addresses the first portion of your question:

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/a3vffhfn/

**JavaScript**

```
var myData = [
  "Name", {
    "Employee": [
      "name",
      "address",
      "phone"
    ]
  },
  "Size",
  "LastName", {
    "Vacation": [
      "name",
      "address",
      "phone"
    ]
  }
];

$(function() {
  $("#desc").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var q = req.term;
      var results = [];
      console.log("Term:", q);
      $.each(myData, function(k, v) {
        console.log(k, v, typeof v);
        if (typeof v == "string") {
          // Item is String
          if (v.indexOf(q) === 0) {
            // If term matches String, add to Results
            results.push(v);
          }
        }
        if (typeof v == "object") {
          // Item is Object
          $.each(v, function(j, z) {
            if (j.indexOf(q) === 0) {
              // Check object keys, if matches, add key to Results
              results.push(j);
            }
          });
        }
      });
      console.log("Results:", results);
      resp(results);
    }
  });
});
```

If you enter "N" or "E", "Name" and "Employee" appear. This does not address the second part of your question. Since you did not specify how you want this data shown, it's not easy to answer.